# Which claim is correct regarding the extrema of a function?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, maxima-minima, extreme-value-analysis

I have a function $f$ and I know that the function has only four unique extrema values which values are fA, fB, fC, and fD; moreover, I know that

- If condition A holds then fA is a **local** maximum of the function
- If condition B holds then fB is a **local** minimum of the function
- If condition C holds then fC is a **local** maximum of the function
- If condition D holds then fD is a **local** minimum of the function

> Now, I want to check for instance if fA can be a **global** maximum while fD is a **global** minimum of the function simultaneously.

**Then, which claim is correct?**

1. It is enough to only check if fA>fD.
2. I should check if the three conditions fA>fD, A and D can be fulfilled simultaneously.

Many thanks in advance for any help and comments.

Comment: 1) Since these extrema are *local*, $fA$ can as well be $<fD.$ 2) It is unclear what you all "conditions A,B,C,D".

Comment: Thanks; I modified my question; now, which claim is correct?

Comment: It is still unclear what you all "conditions A,B,C,D".  Do you mean that each of these only four *potential* local extrema is actual only under the corresponding condition?

Comment: Yes, each extremum happens only with one condition holds.

Comment: Sorry, if my question is confusing; my major is not mathematics and it is likely that I make mistake. In other words, if I have the given information, what are the necessary and sufficient conditions to realize the global minimum and maximum?

Comment: To prove that for instance $fA$ is a global maximum, what you mus prove is: 1) there exists a global maximum, 2) Condition A is fulfilled 3) in case condition C is also fulfilled, $fC\le fA.$ To prove that $fD$ is a global minimum is independent from this and you will have 3 analogous points to prove. For the existence of global extrema, a theorem is useful: for a continuous fuction $f:K\to\Bbb R$, if $K$ is compact then $f$ has a global max and global min. A subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded.